# Change a property within NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uibutton, nsarray

So i got a question how to do the following:
I got an NSArray with Objects.

```
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:object1, object2, nil];
```

object1 and object2 are Subclasses of UIButton. This subclass has a BOOL property (BOOL prop;) which is working fine.

```
object1.prop = YES;
NSLog (@"What does the BOOL say? %@", object1.prop ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

-> Console outputs YES.
Sothis is all working fine, but how can i change the value of prop within the NSArray? For sure things like [[array objectAtIndex:0] anf]; = YES; won't work because of the Syntax, but i don't really know the syntax how to do it.
I'd love if anybody helped me!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[[array objectAtIndex:0] setProp:YES];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of related ways designed to avoid the compiler warnings.  The simplest 'inline' approach is (assume your subclass of UIButton is called MyButton):

```
((MyButton *) array[0]).prop = YES.
```

or (using older syntax):

```
((MyButton *) [array objectAtIndex: 0]).prop = YES.
```

or

```
MyButton *button = (MyButton *) array[0];
button.prop = YES.
```

Comment: In the third case, the cast is not needed.

Comment: Thank you, ((MyButton *) [array objectAtIndex:0]).prop = YES; was what i searched for.

Answer (score 0):

```
[(YourSubclass *)[array objectAtIndex:0] setProp:YES];
```

In general the cast is optional, since NSArray holds objects of the type id. But for code clearness it can harm to cast, so you will see later what you where intending to do.

Comment: The cast is not needed.